# Why does a MySQL query run differently from between the dev and live environment?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, innodb

I have a particular query that runs over 20 seconds in our live environment, but it only takes 0.062 seconds in my dev environment. What would you look for first to troubleshoot something like this? I don't have as much experience troubleshooting DB performance, so a little direction would be a great help. The table is using the InnoDB engine.

Something I noticed with the live environment. The INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE is over 10GB, but the server only has 4GB of RAM. I can't imagine that being good!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: True.  It will lead to swapping, which is much worse than having a smaller buffer_pool.  Recommend no more than 1500M on a 4GB machine.

Comment: If you still have issues after fixing the buffer_pool_size, caching may be the explanation.  Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the other fact like `table schema`, `indexes` are as is and `statistics` are all up to date in both environment.

First thing to check, are the volume of data on both environment same? Cause a query running on 10K records will not have same run-time if it runs on 100K record set.

Again, you pointed that `INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE` is high on live environment but with 4GB in another environment you can't help it. Probably you can compare and set it accordingly in another environment. Like, Compare with RAM size and set it to optimum value in another environment.